# Handling lists with RxJava and Retrofit in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit, rx-java

I have couple of api calls to make (sequentially, asynchronously) and some of them returns lists. My api interface is given below.

```
@GET("/users/settings")
Observable<UserWrapper> getUserSettings();

@GET("/{username}/collections")
Observable<List<Item>> getItems(@Path("username") String userName);

@GET("/item/{id}")
Observable<ItemInfo> getItemInfo(@Path("id") int id);

@GET("/{username}/friends")
Observable<List<Friend>> getFriends(@Path("username") String userName);
```

Here's what I want to do sequentially:

- Get `UserWrapper` by calling `getUserSettings()`
- Save the user by calling `saveUser(userWrapper)`
- Get user's items by calling `getItems(userWrapper.getUserName())`
- Get each item's information by calling `getItemInfo(item.getId())`
- Save each `itemInfo` by calling `saveItem(itemInfo)`
- Get user's friends by calling `getFriends(userWrapper.getUserName())`
- Save each friend by calling `saveFriend(friend)`

Now I am new to RxJava and do not know how to handle lists. I watched one of [Jake Wharton's slides](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/2014-1) and found that he uses a function `flattenList()` but I don't know its definition. It would be great if you can help composing this chain.

---

**Update 1**

This is as far I've gotten now:

```
mApiService.getUserSettings()
            .map(this::saveUser)
            .flatMap(userWrapper -> mApiService.getItems(userWrapper.getUserName()));
            .flatMapIterable( ? "How to iterate for each item" ? );
```

---

**Update 2**

I am trying to write something like this

```
mApiService.getUserSettings()
    .map(this::saveUser)
    .flatMap(userWrapper -> mApiService.getItems(userWrapper.getUserName()))
    .someMethodToIterateThroughEachItem(item -> mApiService.getItemInfo(item))
    .map(this::saveItem)
    .someMethodThatCanCallUserWrapperAgain(userWrapper -> mApiService.getFriends(userWrapper.getUserName()))
    .someMethodToIterateThoughEachFriend(friend -> saveFriend(friend))
```

Comment: What is `someMethodToIterateThroughEachItem`?  How does that compile?

Comment: Please give more details about `someMethodToIterateThroughEachItem`, `someMethodThatCanCallUserWrapperAgain`, and `someMethodToIterateThoughEachFriend`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RxJava has added `flatMapIterable`. So you don't need `flattenList` now. E.g.,

```
  Observable<UserWrapper> o =
       getUserSettings()
       .doOnNext(this::saveUser)
       .flatMap(user -> getItems(user.getUserName())
                        .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
                        .flatMap(item -> getItemInfo(item.getId()))
                        .doOnNext(this::saveItem)
                        .toList()
                        .map(ignored -> user))
        .flatMap(user -> getFriends(user.getUserName())
                         .flatMapIterable(friends -> friends)
                         .doOnNext(this::saveFriend)
                         .toList()
                         .map(ignored -> user)
        );
    o.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks @zsxwing, I have gotten to this point already. Please check my updated question How do I iterate through each item in this call. Isn't there any built in function in RxJava already?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: I've updated the question again for your better understanding. Please read bullet points too. Hope this answers your question.