# RxJava and Retrofit - first steps with Rx

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

With RxJava (without Retrolambda), I would like to do some API calls and complete my data with it. My incomplete object is a 'TvShow' with a list of object 'Season'. This 'Season' is empty and I need to complete it with episodes.

```
Observable<TvShow> getDataTVShow(long idTvShow)
//get TvShow with empty seasons (except season number)

Observable<Season> getDataSeason(long idTvShow, int seasonNumber); 
//get one complete season with episodes
```

So I want to:

- Get my 'TvShow' object **(OK)**
- Iterate over seasons (List <\Season>) from my 'TvShow' object and do for each season an API call to get my season fully completed and update my 'old' season in the list.
- Then once we have all we need, persist data into the database (subscriber part)

Until now, I only have :

```
Observable<TvShow> = apiService.getDataTvShow(idTvShow)
```

I need now to iterate over seasons, I tried to use operator 'map' to switch from 'TvShow' object to my list of seasons (tvShow.getSeasons()) but I'm not sure to be in the good way. Beside that, I know 'doOnNext' will be used to update my 'old' season, that's it.

I tried to work with this good example: [Handling lists with RxJava and Retrofit in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693425/handling-lists-with-rxjava-and-retrofit-in-android)  but I'm still stuck :(

If you can help me solve this problem, it would be great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example you have two observables:

```
Observable<Season> getSeason(int id)
Observable<TvShow> getTvShow(String id)
```

How load TvShow then load each Season and fill TvShow:

```
  Observable<TvShow> getFilledTvShow = getTvShow("123")
      .flatMap(tvShow ->
              //make stream observable from seasons
              Observable.from(tvShow.seasons)
                  //load each season from network
                  .flatMap(season -> getSeason(season.id))
                      //then collect all results to ArrayList
                  .collect(() -> new ArrayList<Season>(),
                      (seasons, filledSeason) -> seasons.add(filledSeason))
                      //finally fill tvShow and return it
                  .map(filledSeasons_ -> {
                     tvShow.seasons = filledSeasons_;
                     return tvShow;
                  })
      );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zella, it's working !! I did not know that we could work on what we return (return Observable.from ...) and then come back at the end with a Observable<TvShow>. By the way, I understand now why lambdas are used, huge difference with my boilerplate code !

Comment: Welcome to the functional world : )

Comment: You may want to use `.toList()` instead of your `collect` method