# Chain Retrofit Queries with Observables (Scraping a Website)

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

I want to scrape results of a web site, by following the pagination links and using retrofit and JavaRx.

This is the idea:

```
service.scrap -> Response
transform(Response) -> Results X paginationToken //somehow store the result 
service.scrap(paginationToken) // Repeat till end of pagination
flatMap // List of Result List into one list results
subscribe //do something with the complete list of results
```

The Question:
How is it possible to emit results to your-self transform them
and do that until you reach some condition, and then to get the full list of results?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759291/rxjava-and-retrofit-first-steps-with-rx